# using 7zip sdk to compress a file, but the archive file is not as original and can not decompress using unrar

Tags: c#, 7zip

I am using 7zip sdk (http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html) to compress a file.

it works fine using this wrapper:

```
public void EncodeSingleFile(FileStream inStream, FileStream outStream)   {
     bool eos = false;
     Int32 dictionary = 1 << 21;
     Int32 posStateBits = 2;
     Int32 litContextBits = 3; // for normal files
     // UInt32 litContextBits = 0; // for 32-bit data
     Int32 litPosBits = 0;
     // UInt32 litPosBits = 2; // for 32-bit data
     Int32 algorithm = 2;
     Int32 numFastBytes = 128;
     string mf = "bt4";

     propIDs = new CoderPropID[]
        {
           CoderPropID.DictionarySize,
           CoderPropID.PosStateBits,
           CoderPropID.LitContextBits,
           CoderPropID.LitPosBits,
           CoderPropID.Algorithm,
           CoderPropID.NumFastBytes,
           CoderPropID.MatchFinder,
           CoderPropID.EndMarker
        };
     properties = new object[]
        {
           dictionary,
           posStateBits,
           litContextBits,
           litPosBits,
           algorithm,
           numFastBytes,
           mf,
           eos
        };

     Encoder encoder = new Encoder();
     encoder.SetCoderProperties(propIDs, properties);
     encoder.WriteCoderProperties(outStream);
     Int64 fileSize = inStream.Length;
     for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
     {
        outStream.WriteByte((Byte) (fileSize >> (8*i)));
     }
     encoder.Code(inStream, outStream, -1, -1, null);
```

}

However, I have got a problem:

I can only decompress it using 7zip shell installed from 7-zip.org, can not decompress with unrar. is that possible if I set some parameters and it will work with unrar as well?

If I open the file in 7zip and check the properties, I got:

- Name: abc.pdb
- Size: 1 809 920
- Packed Size: 249 305
- Method: LZMA:21
- Type: lzma

Comment: If you open your archive in 7-Zip, and check the properties, what does it say for the "Type"?

Comment: I updated that information in my question, it is: lzma

Comment: If I compress it using 7zip shell, the 7zip file has type: 7z. hum, strange.... do you have any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: I've not used that SDK, but I can only assume you've specified the LZMA compresion scheme, and not gzip or whatever.  (LZMA is the scheme used by 7-zip apparently, but I assume there's some other packaging)

Comment: I've just looked at that link - it *is* called "LZMA SDK" - are you sure it will even create any other sort of archive?

Comment: @Cylindric probably, you are right. it is just LZMA library not for 7zip for C# "C# source code for LZMA compression and decompression". hum, this seems strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example on CodeProject of someone creating a C# interface for 7z using the SDK.  He also mentions it is now possible to use COM against the DLL's, but I don't know how that works.

Check out [C# (.NET) Interface for 7-Zip Archive DLLs](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/DLL/cs_interface_7zip.aspx) on The Code Project.

Comment: This is with DLL, I want to avoid that so I went to use the SDK. It is working so far however the problem is that it can not decompress with winrar. I am trying to solve the issue. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to create a RAR archive, you may be out of luck, as it is closed-source.  You can probably use external libraries, but the compression algorithm is proprietary.

From the [RAR Wiki Page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAR):

> RAR files may be created only with commercial software WinRAR, RAR, and software that has permission from the licensor Alexander Roshal

I would recommend investigating one of the many unencumbered alternatives.

Comment: no, the purpose is to make it as 7z. but the problem is that the result I got from the sdk can not decompress using winrar. if I use the shell execution of 7z to compress. I can then decompress it using winrar

Comment: Ah, fair enough then.  I guess maybe it's using a variant of the 7-zip format that WinRAR doesn't understand.  I don't suppose "don't use WinRAR" is an option? :)

Comment: Does it *have* to be 7z format?  I've used the [Ionic DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) library to great success, but it creates zip archives.