# Using 7zip sdk to compress a Folder

Tags: c#, sdk, 7zip, compression

We decided to use 7zip SDK to compress and decompress files and folders. I know there are many [libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222030/how-do-i-create-7-zip-archives-with-net) for that but we decided to use the SDK directly. I have seen a sample code that uses the SDK to compress\decompress a [file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8339179/using-7zip-sdk-to-compress-a-file-but-can-not-decompress-using-winrar-or-7zip/8339548#8339548) but I could not find a way to do that for Folders.
Would appreciate if anyone could share a c# code that uses 7zip SDK directly that can compress\decompress Folders. I do not want to use the 7z.exe (saw many answers to [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255968/how-would-i-compress-a-folder-with-7zip-in-c) also)

Comment: There are several libraries like [SevenZipSharp] (https://sevenzipsharp.codeplex.com/), [SharpCompress](https://github.com/adamhathcock/sharpcompress) , [managed=lzma](https://github.com/weltkante/managed-lzma) and more (Look at the links I provided in the question). Every library has it's pro\con so finally we decided to use straight the SDK but missing the knowledge on how to zip a folder. A file we know how to do [that](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646328/how-to-use-the-7z-sdk-to-compress-and-decompress-a-file).

Comment: Specifically the SevenZipSharp has poor performance when we need to zip a large number of files (+10,000) and I understand it is no longer supported